# Compile option for C only in visual studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

Is there a compiler option in visual studio 2012 that tells it to compile C only and not C++?  I am porting some legacy C code into visual studio.  There are cases where the code compares pointers to functions like strchr.  In C strchr has only one prototype, but in C++ it has two.  That causes errors when the C++ compiler cannot determine which prototype to use.  Instead of having to change all the code, I'd like to just be able to tell the compiler to compile C and not C++.  Is this possible?

Comment: When I said "porting legacy code", that implied existing syntax, files, file names, extensions (.c), etc.  The goal is to make as few changes as possible, just get it to compile in VS.

Comment: Right-click the file, Properties, C/C++, Advanced, "Compile As" setting.  This is supposed to be discoverable, spend an hour or so looking through these settings and press F1 if you have no idea what a specific setting might mean.

Answer (score 2):

Just name the source files .c instead of .cpp.

Comment: The source files do have .c extensions, not .cpp.  I'm looking for an option to tell the compiler to follow C rules and not C++ rules, like /C99 for example.  The /Za option disables M'soft extensions so why can't there be something similar for C/C++?

Comment: @storax70681: If you have extension .c, Visual Studio will by default use the C compiler, not the C++ compiler. Perhaps you have added a flag such as /TP? Otherwise, /TC should work. See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The `__STDC__` precompiler macro might do what I need:

> "Indicates full conformance with the ANSI C standard. Defined as the integer constant 1 only if the /Za compiler option is given and you are not compiling C++ code; otherwise is undefined."

Comment: \_\_STDC\_\_ is just a way to check if the compiler follows the C standard. It won't change anything.